# extract substring in R

Tags: r, regex, substring

Suppose I have list of string `"S[+229]EC[+57]VDSTDNSSK[+229]PSSEPTSHVAR"` and need to get a vector of string that contains only numbers with bracket like  eg. `[+229][+57]`.

Is there a convenient way in *R* to do this?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I think your edit introduced `_` into the string. @Gattu did you want output as you list `[+229][+57]` or rather all bracketed numbers `[+229][+57][+229]` ?

Comment: @MartinMorgan yes, sorry fixed it. The underscore was for italics in the original post. I thought it was part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`, then try it with

```
> unlist(regmatches(s,gregexpr("\\[\\+\\d+\\]",s)))
[1] "[+229]" "[+57]"  "[+229]"
```

Or you can use

```
> gsub(".*?(\\[.*\\]).*","\\1",gsub("\\].*?\\[","] | [",s))
[1] "[+229] | [+57] | [+229]"
```

Comment: Hi Thomas I used                                                                                                                           > gsub("[^\\[\\]+0-9]+","",s,perl = T)
[1] "[+229][+57][+229]"                                                                                                      but how can I separate each bracket with | for eg.  [+229] | [+57] | [+229]?

Comment: @Gattu Do you mean the output like `"[+229] | [+57] | [+229]" ` ? Then you may have a try with `gsub(".*?(\\[.*\\]).*","\\1",gsub("\\].*?\\[","] | [",s))`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Yes that was exactly I was looking for

Comment: @Gattu Great! Then I will add that to my solution. If you like, you can accept my answer and then close the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\[\\+\\d+\\]")[[1]]
#[1] "[+229]" "[+57]"  "[+229]"
```

Wrap it in `unique` if you need only unique values.

---

Similarly, in base R using `regmatches` and `gregexpr`

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\[\\+\\d+\\]", x))[[1]]
```

**data**

```
x <- "S[+229]EC[+57]VDSTDNSSK[+229]PSSEPTSHVAR"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. How can i insert | for eg.  [+229]|[+57]|[+229]

Comment: @Gattu you can do `paste0(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\[\\+\\d+\\]", x))[[1]], collapse = "|")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to remove the alphabetical characters, so

```
gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", x)
```

where `[:alpha:]` is the class of alphabetical (lower-case and upper-case) characters, `[[:alpha:]]` says 'match any single alphabetical character', and `gsub()` says substitute, globally, any alphabetical character with the empty string `""`. This seems better than trying to match bracketed numbers, which requires figuring out which characters need to be escaped with a (double!) `\\`.

If the intention is to return the *unique* bracketed numbers, then the approach is to extract the matches (rather than remove the unwanted characters). Instead of using `gsub()` to substitute matches to a regular expression with another value, I'll use `gregexpr()` to identify the matches, and `regmatches()` to extract the matches. Since numbers always occur in `[]`, I'll simplify the regular expression to match one or more (`+`) characters from the collection `+[:digit:]`.

```
> xx <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("[+[:digit:]]+", x))
> xx
[[1]]
[1] "+229" "+57"  "+229"
```

`xx` is a list of length equal to the length of `x`. I'll write a function that, for any element of this list, makes the values unique, surrounds the values with `[` and `]`, and concatenates them

```
fun <- function(x)
    paste0("[", unique(x), "]", collapse = "")
```

This needs to be applied to each element of the list, and simplified to a vector, a task for `sapply()`.

```
> sapply(xx, fun)
[1] "[+229][+57]"
```

A minor improvement is to use `vapply()`, so that the result is robust (always returning a character vector with length equal to `x`) to zero-length inputs

```
> x = character()
> xx <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("[+[:digit:]]+", x))
> sapply(xx, fun)               # Hey, this returns a list :(
list()
> vapply(xx, fun, "character")  # vapply() deals with 0-length inputs
character(0)
```